# Compute the correlation coefficient $r(X_{(1)},X_{(3)})$ .

Tags: probability-distributions, correlation, means, order-statistics

I got this problem where:

The random variables $X_1, X_2,$ and $X_3$ are independent and $Exp(1)-$
distributed.
Compute the correlation coefficient $r(X_{(1)},X_{(3)})$ .

---

I know through research that: $\mathrm E(X_{(k)})=\sum\limits_{i=n-k+1}^n\frac1i,\qquad
\mbox{Var}(X_{(k)})=\sum\limits_{i=n-k+1}^n\frac1{i^2}.$

I could find everything except, $E(X_{(1)}X_{(3)})$.

I got: $E(X_{(1)})=\frac {1}{3},\qquad E(X_{(3)})=1+\frac {1}{2}+\frac {1}{3}$

$Var(X_{(1)})= \frac {1}{9},  \qquad Var(X_{(3)})= 1+\frac {1}{4}+\frac {1}{9}$

I also know that correlation =
 $$ \frac{cov(X_{(1)},X_{(3)})}{\sqrt{Var(X_{(1)})Var(X_{(3)})}}$$

---

**Update**:

So from the implication of @NcH I figured the  $E(X_{(1)}X_{(3)})=1$ 
But, when trying to compute the correlation coefficient I get 1 as the final answer as opposed to 2/7 suggested by the textbook.

$$r= \frac{1-11/18}{7/18}=1$$

Anyone has a different answer ?

Comment: Your solutions assume that the sample size is 3, but this not stated in the question. The answer should therefore be a function of the sample size $n$.

Comment: Side note, the answer is 2/7

Comment: @wolfies it is explicitly stated in the question, while OP used the results which are true for sample size $n$ and $k$-th order statistics.

Comment: @pointguard Why would the expectation of the sample minimum in a sample of size $n$ be equal to $\frac13$?

Comment: it is not equal to $\frac 1 3$, it is equal to $\sum_{i=n-k+1}^n \frac 1 i$.

Comment: Keep on reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the simplest way is to use joint PDF of $X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(3)}$. For $0<x<y$ using formula for [[joint pdf of two order ststistics][1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_an_absolutely_continuous_distribution)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_an_absolutely_continuous_distribution)
we get
$$
f_{X_{(1)}, X_{(3)}}(x,y) = 3! \bigl((1-e^{-y})-(1-e^{-x})\bigr)e^{-x}e^{-y}=6(e^{-2x-y}-e^{-x-2y})
$$

Then $$\mathbb E[X_{(1)}X_{(3)}]=\iint_{0<x<y<\infty} xy f_{X_{(1)}, X_{(3)}}(x,y) \,dx\, dy.$$

Comment: I guess you're just missing the 6 at the end of your joint. Aside that thank you for your reply

Comment: I got 1 as final answer even though the solution suggest 2/7

Comment: Thanks, I added lost $6$. No, this integral is not equal to $1$. Wolframalpha gives answer $\frac{13}{18}$.

Comment: x goes from 0 to y and y goes from 0 to $\infty$ right ?

Comment: Oh yeah you're right I see my error